# Implementing an algorithm in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I am trying to implement the algorithm provided here [Lets Build A 3D Graphics Engine](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/lets-build-a-3d-graphics-engine-points-vectors-and-basic-concepts--gamedev-8143) with javascript.So far I have made this far but its not working properly. Here's the code.

```js
    var Class = function(methods) {
      var klass = function() {
        this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
      };

      for (var property in methods) {
        klass.prototype[property] = methods[property];
      }

      if (!klass.prototype.initialize) klass.prototype.initialize = function() {};

      return klass;
    };


     // Point class


    var Point = Class({

      initialize: function(x, y, z)

      {
        var tuple;
        this.tuple = [x, y, z];
      },

      addVectorToPoint: function(Vector)

      {
        var a = this.tuple[0] + Vector.tuple[0];

        var b = this.tuple[1] + Vector.tuple[1];

        var c = this.tuple[2] + Vector.tuple[2];

        return [a, b, c];

      },

      subtractVectorFromPoint: function(Vector)

      {
        var a = this.tuple[0] - Vector.tuple[0];

        var b = this.tuple[1] - Vector.tuple[1];

        var c = this.tuple[2] - Vector.tuple[2];

        return [a, b, c];

      },

      subtractPointFromPoint: function(Point)

      {
        var a = this.tuple[0] - Point.tuple[0];

        var b = this.tuple[1] - Point.tuple[1];

        var c = this.tuple[2] - Point.tuple[2];

        return [a, b, c];

      },



      drawPoint: function()

      {
        document.writeln(this.tuple);
      }

    });





     // Vector class..............

    var Vector = Class({

      initialize: function(X, Y, Z)

      {
        var tuple;
        this.tuple = [X, Y, Z];
      },

      addVectorToVector: function(Vector)

      {
        var a = this.tuple[0] + Vector.tuple[0];

        var b = this.tuple[1] + Vector.tuple[1];

        var c = this.tuple[2] + Vector.tuple[2];

        return [a, b, c];

      },

      subtractVectorFromVector: function(Vector)

      {
        var a = this.tuple[0] - Vector.tuple[0];

        var b = this.tuple[1] - Vector.tuple[1];

        var c = this.tuple[2] - Vector.tuple[2];

        return [a, b, c];

      },

      drawPoint: function()

      {
        document.writeln(this.tuple);
      }

    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>



</head>


<body>





  <script src="new.js"></script>

  <script>
    var point1 = new Point(1, 2, 1);
    var point2 = new Point(0, 4, 4);
    var vector1 = new Vector(2, 0, 0);
    var vector2;

    point1.drawPoint(); //should display (1,2,1)
    point2.drawPoint(); //should display (0,4,4)
    vector1.drawPoint();

    vector2 = point1.subtractPointFromPoint(point2);

    vector1 = vector1.addVectorToVector(vector2);

    point1.addVectorToPoint(vector1);
    point1.drawPoint(); //should display (4,0,-2)

    point2.subtractVectorFromPoint(vector2);
    point2.drawPoint(); //should display (-1,6,7)
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Its providing me this error.

> TypeError: Vector.tuple is undefined new.js:95

Please help as soon as possible.
Thanks inn advance.

Comment: Should your functions not accept  vector (instead of Vector) instead of Vector ? For example subtractVectorFromVector: function(vector) ??

Comment: uhh that didn't help either. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `subtractPointFromPoint` returns a tuple `return [a, b, c];` which then you pass to `addVectorToVector` and you take `.tuple` on it. That's why it doesn't work. I assume that if you change

```
return [a, b, c];
```

to

```
return new Vector(a, b, c);
```

in `subtractPointFromPoint` (and possibly other places) then it should work.

Comment: Yeah thanks I guess it will help but I cant find out because now its giving.
TypeError: this.initialize is undefined                           new.js:3

Comment: @JoydeepBhattacharya My mistake, forgotten about `new` keyword (see above).

Comment: Ok I'm gonna see if that helps. Btw I think I have to change every return value like this. Isn't it? Again thanks for helping.

Comment: @JoydeepBhattacharya Not every return value, but some of them. You have to analyze which functions return vectors and which return points and add `new Vector`/`new Point` to them.

Comment: I did this. Hope its right.      
But now its showing TypeError: Vector is not a constructor         new.js:101

Comment: oops I'm sorry the argument & class names were conflicting.